# How to slice a pandas dataframe (get a subset)?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

How to slice a dataframe to a subset dataframe at specific x,y positions?

E.g. how to get the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right and the middle 2x2 regions as subset dataframes?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [16, 3, 2, 13],
    [5, 10, 11, 8],
    [9, 6, 7, 12],
    [4, 15, 14, 1]            
])
```

Expected:

```py
# top-left 2x2
[
    [16, 3],
    [5, 10]         
]
# center 2x2
[
    [10, 11],
    [16, 17]         
]

# etc for top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right.
```

Comment: please provide the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the underlying numpy array (you could also use pandas and `iloc` but why make things more complicated?)

```
a = df.values
x,y = a.shape
X,Y = x//2,y//2
a[:2,:2],a[-2:,:2],a[:2,-2:],a[-2:,-2:],a[X-1:X+1, Y-1:Y+1]
```

output:

```
(array([[16,  3],
        [ 5, 10]]),
 array([[ 9,  6],
        [ 4, 15]]),
 array([[ 2, 13],
        [11,  8]]),
 array([[ 7, 12],
        [14,  1]]),
 array([[10, 11],
        [ 6,  7]]))
```